# Mui v5 - How to migrate away from withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've spent a day on the change notes and other docs for v5 and can see `withStyles` is not recommended anymore, in favor of `sx`. However, `withStyles` provided something that `sx` did not: a way to take an existing component and style all aspects of it without touching the underlying API.

Take the following example:

```
export const ResourceCardHeader = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        paddingBottom: 0,
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
            paddingTop: theme.spacing(1),
        },
    },
    content: {
        borderBottom: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
        paddingBottom: '5px',
        width: '100%',

        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: '1.1rem',
        fontWeight: 700,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('font-size', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
        }),

        // Hide around x button
        maxWidth: 'calc(100% - 8px)',

        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            fontSize: '0.9rem',
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            fontSize: '0.75rem',
        },
    },
    subheader: {
        fontSize: '0.8rem',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('font-size', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
        }),

        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            fontSize: '0.6rem',
        },
    },
}))(CardHeader)
```

This is doing... a lot. Moving it to `sx` seems unreasonable and worse. I would also have to import and re-export the underlying component/props as far as I can tell. More importantly, I can access the styles of the individual inner components (content, title etc). This in all lets me restyle the card component to a very granular level for a specific component. I can't see how `sx` gives me that, not can I tell what I should be doing instead.

I would also rather migrate away entirely from JSS if possible to keep up to date with the latest mui standards.

What would be the best approach to migrate this Header and other components like it to a more v5-y approach?

Comment: Have you tried the codemods yet? Documented on V5 migration guide

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann I have tried the codemods as per the migration guide yeah . It broke a couple of things for me. It kept the above code as is but deleted all my custom breakpoints (xs became sm and custom values (i.e. numbers) became undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CreateMuiTheme like global theme for some components and then just in components where you need specific style use other theme wrapper or another style. Also for component styles you can use makeStyles